# Antlr4 parsing two Integers separated by double-dots delimiter failed to match integers

Tags: regex, parsing, grammar, antlr4

I'm trying to parse one token with pattern `<int1>..<int2>` in antlr4, and what I'm doing now is a trivial approach like:

```
main: INT1 '..' INT2;
INT1: NUMBER;
INT2: NUMBER;
NUMBER: [0-9]+ ;
```

However, when I tried to test the rule main with input `1..10` I got the error:

> mismatched input '1' expecting NUMBER

which means I will always miss match the first int, BUT MY second int will be matched.

I was really confused, I think given the token `<int1>` and `<int2>` the same `NUMBER` lexer rule should result in same match, but clearly it doesn't do the job in my case. Anyone has any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Try some other tests to make sure you understand exactly where it's failing - for example, `1..2`, `3..45`, `67..89` - the error you're receiving doesn't actually indicate whether it's failing on the `1` by itself or the `1` that is part of `10`.

Comment: I tried all those combinations, they all failed to match only the first integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confused concepts of tokens and syntax rules.
Your grammar contains two tokens (INT and '..') and one rule:

```
main: int1=INT '..' int2=INT;

INT: [0-9]+ ;
```

Comment: Thanks, that explained just perfectly, it solved my problem.

Comment: Actually, the concept is rather: the grammar consists of parser and lexer rules. Lexer rules are used to assign a token type to a group of input symbols (the used type is usually what is used for the rule name, but it can also be a different type). Parser rules use these tokens to match them against the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

As @KvanTTT mentioned in his answer, I messed up the token rules and syntax rules. My approach also works in this way:

```
main: int1 '..' int2;
int1: NUMBER;
int2: NUMBER;
NUMBER: [0-9]+ ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is this: you have 2 lexer rules matching the same input. Only one can match, however. ANTLR uses the longer match. If there are multiple rules matching the same length then the first one wins.

Btw. an important tip if you have trouble matching your input: print your tokens as they came in (use the token stream for that). In your case you probably got: `INT1, .., INT1`, which obviously doesn't match your grammar.